# Is it okay to ask questions that validate my understanding on a concept in artificial intelligence?

Tags: discussion

I may get many questions to check whether my understanding of a particular concept in artificial intelligence is correct or not.

For example, you can check the question [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/31821/mathematically-speaking-is-it-only-the-product-operation-used-in-the-chain-rule). Like this, I may get many questions for which I am slightly ambiguous and/or confused about my own understanding.

If I start asking the questions, I will surely get benefited because of the reason that I may get acknowledgement from the experts whether my understanding is correct or not. But I am not sure whether this act will be *useful for the site and site progress*. So please guide me in this aspect.

I think that if my understanding is either completely wrong or partially wrong then it can be highly useful for me and maybe helpful for our main site also to some extent. But if my understanding is exactly correct then experts may just comment, which may not be very helpful for this site. So I am getting confusion about asking such questions.

Is it ok to ask questions on our main site to check whether my understanding of your particular concept is correct or not?

Answer (score 1):

I think so.  But **how you ask in important**.

- Questions that simply produce a simple "yes" are not good questions
- Questions that produce a "no" might not be either

i.e. **avoid questions that may result in Boolean output.**

Better to ask about some concept in general, not necessarily presenting your own knowledge, and let the answerer provide the details.

- It's almost better to do a self Q&A, then let others vote and provide alternate answers.

Think about it before you post, but I won't hold it against you if we find that some questions are unsuitable and must close.

But don't spam question until you get a sense of what is a suitable way to ask, and, ideally, the community weighs in via voting.

You have sufficient rep that you can take some hits, and you can always delete the question that get heavily downvoted.

Maybe try one, gauge the result, then try another.

- We definitely need more questions, and questions on concepts and theory would be ideal.